Why I am getting this error when I try to do npm install?
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\jerome.peterjoshua\Projects\smart_factory_assemblytraceability_wamp\wamp\node_modules\sqlite3
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install -r napi || node-gyp rebuild
npm error prebuild-install warn install unable to get local issuer certificate
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm error gyp info using node@18.20.3 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.6 found at "C:\Users\jerome.peterjoshua\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.20.3/node-v18.20.3-headers.tar.gz
npm error gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm error gyp ERR! configure error
npm error gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.20.3/node-v18.20.3-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jerome.peterjoshua\Projects\smart_factory_assemblytraceability_wamp\wamp\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:529:35)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm error gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jerome.peterjoshua\\Projects\\smart_factory_assemblytraceability_wamp\\wamp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jerome.peterjoshua\Projects\smart_factory_assemblytraceability_wamp\wamp\node_modules\sqlite3    
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v18.20.3
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm error gyp ERR! not ok

I tried uninstall and install node, tried to set strict-ssl false, tried npm cache clean --force but nothing is working.

Not sure what the reason is, but you may be able to avoid the issue by following the suggestions in the answers to npm install error - unable to get local issuer certificate
